# 'View previous replies' on Instagram and LinkedIn... but why?

Tags: social-media, comments, social

Instagram and LinkedIn both show the most recent replies to comments first, and then you have to click to 'view previous replies', effectively working your way backwards towards the first reply. So if you want to follow a thread of conversation you have to click many times (depending on how many total replies there are) until all the replies are visible and then read back through them in the order they were posted. I just can't figure out why this is the way they both choose to do it, as for me it provides a frustrating experience on the regs! Can anyone explain the logic behind this pattern?

Answer (score 4):

It probably means that they want to encourage novelty over discussion. See this other question for some more general discussion on comment-order [Display comments order - best practice](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38002/display-comments-order-best-practice).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to ask them.

They might not know either.

Corporate Inertia may well mean that whoever did decide to do it this way has long since left the company.

And no one has questioned it since...